# Excel Sparkline show straight line, linked cell is empty

Tags: excel

I have linked cell with the equitation to a sparkline cell. The problem is that the original cell is empty, however, sparkline shows the straight line. The idea is that whenever new data will be entered sparkline will draw a graph.

Original cell name “Monthly Burn Rate”. Sparkline “Burn Rate”

Hopefully, it makes sense what I am trying to say.
Attached screenshot

[MOnthly Burn Rate cell equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yP3d.png)

[Sparkline Cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPofH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your formula to:

```
=IF((L22+L14-L13-L27)/3 = 0, NA(), (L22+L14-L13-L27)/3)
```

This works because Excel charts and sparklines ignore NA errors

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, It solved the problem with sparklines. However, in the original Burn rate cell, it shows #N/A

Comment: What you need to do is to have two formulas: the original formula for the Burn Rate cell, and then another formula in a cell that the users can't see, with the formula `=IF(L40=0,NA(),L40)` and then point your sparkline at that cell.

Comment: You must be misunderstanding me...it works fine. What doesn't work for you? Can you post a screenshot?